# exec $SHELL results in error messages

Tags: command-line

I tried to install virtualenvwrapper and pyenv on my Ubuntu machine. I'm not sure what I did wrong, but now, when I run this command:

```
$ exec $SHELL
```

I see an error message saying that

> No module named virtualenvwrapper

But I'm not sure how can I correct all this. The question is not about virtualenvwrapper itself, but about the root cause of such an error. I need to know what should I do, when I face such errors, trying to `$ exec $SHELL`.

Comment: I guess, I did something wrong with `echo ...' >> ~/.bashrc` commands. And it is possible, that I need to edit something and I' not sure what.

Comment: what were the steps in installing _virtualenwrapper_ please post that it would help.